# Misunderstanding the concept of semantic consequence

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In my course notes I have a statement like this one:

> Let $F_1, ..., F_n \in FOL$. We say that $F$ is a semantic consequence from $F_1, ..., F_n$ and we denote that by $F_1, ..., F_n \vDash F$ if for every structure $S$ for which $S(F_1) = ... = S(F_n) = 1$ we have that $S(F) = 1$.

And there ar some examples:

> $(\forall)P(x) \vDash P(c)$
>
> $P(c) \rightarrow Q(x), P(c) \vDash Q(x)$

As I understand, for every structure in which $P(c)$ is true, then $Q(x)$ is also going to be true. But how does that happen? For example, if I interpret $P(x)$ as $x < 10$, $c$  as $4$ and $Q(x)$ as $x > 0$ and $x$ as $-1$. Then, in this structure, $P(c)$ will be true, but $Q(c)$ will be false. What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO; for every structure in which $P(c)$ **and** $P(c) \to Q(x)$ are true, then $Q(x)$ is also true.

Thus, if $P(c)$ is *true*, by truth-table for the *conditional*, the only possibility left when $P(c) \to Q(x)$ is *true* is that $Q(x)$ is *true* also.

If you interpret $P(x)$ as $x < 10$, $c$ as $4$ and $Q(x)$ as $x>0$ $x$ as $−1$, in this structure, $P(c)$ will be true, but $P(c) \to Q(x)$ will be false :

> $(4 < 10) \to (-1 > 0)$

is $TRUE \to FALSE$, i.e. $FALSE$, and thus the definition of *semantic consequence* is not violated.

Comment: sorry, there's also $(\forall)P(x) \vDash P(c)$.

Comment: @cristid9 - if so, then edit you question ...

Comment: @cristid9 - obviously, $\forall x P(x) \vDash P(c)$ holds: if all the objects are $P$s, then also the object named $c$ is a $P$.